# How to know which Button was pressed recently among all the Buttons in an activity?

Tags: android, button

I have three `Buttons` named  `button1`,`button2`,`button3` in my activity.In `button3` `onclickListener(`), I should know which `Button` was pressed recently between the buttons  `button1` and `button2`.

Comment: Dont you have click method for each button ?

Comment: i have that method.But when i press the button 3,i need to know which button was pressed recently between button1 and button 2.

Comment: i got the answer yaar.Thanks for your interest.

Comment: You welcome. Next time when you have question, please post the code with error if any. Otherwise you will get lots of downvotes like this question.

Comment: Ok, Also keep this in mind that you need to accept the answer which is most suitable to your question. Just tick the tick mark besides the answer which is most helpful for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep a local variable and set it to the appropriate button's id whenever a button is pressed.

```
int lastPressedButton;
...
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    lastPressedButton = v.getId();

    switch(v.getId()) {
        // normal button handling code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the `Button` are in a reusable `View` like `ListView` following way will help you.
 Dynamically set `tag` to each `Button` like follow,

```
button1.setTag("button1");
button2.setTag("button2");
button3.setTag("button3");
```

Then in the `onClick` method,

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), v.getTag()+" Clicked",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

If `Button` is in a simple `Activity`

```
 @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button1:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()," Button 1 Clicked",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
           case R.id.button2:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()," Button 2 Clicked",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onClick(View v) {
switch(v.getId())
{
case R.id.b1:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()," First Button  Clicked",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
case R.id.b2:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()," Second Button  Clicked",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
}
}
```